# Convert array of Callables into one Callable

Tags: php, php-7.4

How to create a callback function that has multiple callback functions from an array:

```
$fn = function() { echo '1';};
$fn2 = function() { echo '2';};

$array = [
    $fn,
    $fn2
];

$callback = ... $array; // Calls first $fn then $fn2.
```

Bigger context:

I am using some library where some class has a callback function as a property, this refers to a function that can be executed before the actual operation.

```
public function before(callable $fn)
{
    $this->before = $fn;

    return $this;
}
```

By default, for my work, I fill it with a certain function, so you can't add another one.

Due to the fact that the class has `$this->before` and few key methods privately created, I am not able to overwrite by my own classes and I unfortunately it is a third-party library and I can't make changes to it

I came up with the idea of overriding the class and the main method that is used to set this callback so that my class will have an array, and at the point of adding the callback function before calling the parent, I will create one callback function from all the functions added to the array.

```
/**
 * @var callable[]
 */
private array $beforeCallbacks = [];

public function before(callable $fn): ChildrenClass
{
    $this->beforeCallbacks[] = $fn;
    
    foreach ($this->beforeCallbacks as $callback) {
        if (!isset($newCallback)) {
            $newCallback = $callback;
        }
        $newCallback .= $callback;  // As you can guess, it doesn't work:C
    }
    return parent::before($newCallback); 
}
```

Any suggestions?

I wonder if that's even possible.
And what if I wanted to inject a parameter into each function, is there any way to handle this?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Your code got the inheritance order completely wrong.

Comment: Of course, I can change the library code, but I can't imagine doing it every day after "composer update"

Comment: @ChrisHaas I edited the question as you suggested to make it less confusing.
Ok, I thought you were the person who voted against the question because your comment appeared at the same time as the question's rating. Personally, I don't have a problem with it, but I just wanted to know the reason to be able to improve it, so that it can help others in the future

Comment: *"but I can't imagine doing it every day after `composer update`"* - Finally, someone who understands why you shouldn't modify vendor code directly!  (I see people doing that far too often). Sidenote, if the library is open-source, you _can_ fork it, fix it, and use that (and or attempt to merge it back into the base repository, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to wrap your callbacks in a structure that can handle calling multiple and in the order you want. The version below uses `__invoke` but you could do whatever callable syntax for PHP that you want.

```php
class MultipleCaller {
    private $callbacks = [];
    public function addCallback(callable $fn) {
        $this->callbacks[] = $fn;
    }
    
    public function __invoke() {
        foreach($this->callbacks as $callback) {
            $callback();
        }
    }
}

$mc = new MultipleCaller();
$mc->addCallback(static function () { echo 1, PHP_EOL; } );
$mc->addCallback(static function () { echo 2, PHP_EOL; } );

$mc();
```

**edit**

Yes, arguments can be passed. One option is to use `...` to pass things through

```php
class MultipleCaller {
    private $callbacks = [];
    public function addCallback(callable $fn) {
        $this->callbacks[] = $fn;
    }
    
    public function __invoke(...$args) {
        foreach($this->callbacks as $callback) {
            $callback(...$args);
        }
    }
}

$mc = new MultipleCaller();
$mc->addCallback(static function (...$args) { echo 'Function 1', PHP_EOL, var_dump($args), PHP_EOL; } );
$mc->addCallback(static function (...$args) { echo 'Function 2', PHP_EOL, var_dump($args), PHP_EOL; } );

function doWork(callable $fn, ...$args) {
    $fn(...$args);
}

doWork($mc, 'alpha', 'beta');
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/TGdJq

`func_get_args` could also be used in a similar fashion

**edit 2**

The magic `__invoke` can be skipped, too, if you'd rather have a more explicit method to call. You could then use `[$mc, 'invoke']` or the more modern `$mc->invoke(...)` syntax.

```php
<?php

class MultipleCaller {
    private $callbacks = [];
    public function addCallback(callable $fn) {
        $this->callbacks[] = $fn;
    }
    
    public function invoke(...$args) {
        foreach($this->callbacks as $callback) {
            $callback(...$args);
        }
    }
}

$mc = new MultipleCaller();
$mc->addCallback(static function (...$args) { echo 'Function 1', PHP_EOL, var_dump($args), PHP_EOL; } );
$mc->addCallback(static function (...$args) { echo 'Function 2', PHP_EOL, var_dump($args), PHP_EOL; } );

function doWork(callable $fn, ...$args) {
    $fn(...$args);
}

doWork([$mc, 'invoke'], 'alpha', 'beta');
doWork($mc->invoke(...), 'alpha', 'beta');
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Zd1De#v8.2.2

Comment: It is possible to pass arguments to this methods by passing $mc('Some value'); for example?

Comment: Great! Now I'm left with the biggest problem I always have: Which solution to choose :D
The effect is the same, but I cannot judge the differences in ideas.

Comment: The two solutions are essentially identical at the end of the day, one is just more OOP than the other. The OOP version has the advantage of type-checking by enforcing the `callable` type when calling the `addCallback` method. Also, if you think that OOP code is easier to read (which I do), it feels less magic and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$fn = function() { var_dump('First');};
$fn2 = function() { var_dump('Second');};
$fn3 = function() { var_dump(func_get_args());};

$array = [
    $fn,
    $fn2,
    $fn3
];

$callback = function () use ($array) {
    foreach ($array as $fn) {
        $fn(...func_get_args());
    }
};

$callback('Passed parameter');
```

will display:

```
string(5) "First"
string(6) "Second"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "Passed parameter"
}
```